# How does corner transport differ from advection schemes?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, computational-physics, geophysics

I was curious what the difference between corner transport and regular advection schemes.

Usually models approximate advection by plugging in $1 D$ flux approximations for $\frac{d Qx}{dx}$, $\frac{d Qx}{dy}$, and $\frac{d Qx}{dz}$ (9th order for example), and they plug that into $$u \frac{d Qx}{dx} + v \frac{d Qx}{dy} + w \frac{d Qx}{dz}$$
that would just be for the x-direction.

How does corner transport differ from this process?

In reference to this post, [9-point stencil “equivalent” for advection equation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/195671/9-point-stencil-equivalent-for-advection-equation).

Answer (score 0):

The difference is provided in the linked answer: the typical advection scheme as you describe truncates the Taylor series approximation to second order in $\Delta t^2$ (so accurate to $\Delta t$) while the CTU advection in the linked shows extension to third order (accurate to $\Delta t^2$):

> Typically, we get the finite difference schemes via Taylor expansion, keeping 1st order terms and ignoring the rest (as either small, or naturally via subtraction a la central difference). The CTU scheme *keeps* these 2nd order terms, so the expansion is
> \begin{align}
> Q\left(t+\Delta t,x,y\right)&=Q-\Delta t\left[uQ_{,x}+vQ_{,y}\right] \\
> &+\frac12\Delta t^2\left[u^2Q_{,xx}+vuQ_{,xy}+uvQ_{,yx}+v^2Q_{,yy}\right]+\mathcal{O}\left(\Delta t^3\right)
> \end{align}

Extension of the above to a third dimension is straight-forward, simply adding additional derivative to the first bracketed term and cross terms ($Q_{,xz}$, $Q_{yz}$, etc) in the second line.

If your model is using an $n$th-order scheme for the spatial component of the advection, then using CTU could improve the *temporal* accuracy, though you probably would want to check on how it'd compare to say Runge-Kutta integration or other time-stepping routines (e.g., it might be "cheaper" or faster to run another time-stepping scheme instead of extending CTU scheme to an additional few stencil points needed for CTU, as it'd make boundaries a little harder, I guess).